# Configure Mvc Mini Profiler with Linq DataCotext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, mvc-mini-profiler

I'm using linq-to-sql datacontext for an application.
I have the following class

UserDataContext which I instantiate the table with

```
var db = new UserDataContext();
```

How do I make Mvc Mini Profiler insert into that?

I tried to extend UserDataContext with the following partial found at another answer, but the code is never hit.

```
partial class UserDataContext
{    
public static UserDataContext Get()
    {
        var sqlConnection = new HelpSaudeAPDataContext().Connection;
        var profiledConnection = new MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbConnection(new SqlConnection("UserConnectionString"), MiniProfiler.Current);
        return new HelpSaudeAPDataContext(profiledConnection);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately there is no single point repository with the var db connection where I could simply pass the mvc mini profiler connection with.

```
var db = UserDataContext(profilerConnection);
```

Comment: You know what. Your question actually helped me solve another issue (being a noob) But - Never the less. Your question was my answer! Thanks +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but the code is never hit.

Well, hit it:

```
var db = UserDataContext.Get();
```

Comment: I should've though before asking this question -_-

Comment: Isn't that the way it always happens? Ask a question, then something dawns on you :)